# Kubernetes deployment for mysql

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to get a kubernetes deployment with mysql such that I could connect to it from my host computer.

here's the deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: database
        image: mysql:5.6
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_USER 
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: username
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD 
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: password
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "250m"
            memory: "1Gi"
      volumes:  
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 32700
  externalIPs:
  - 1.2.4.8
```

If I run `minikube service list` this gets shown:

```
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
|      NAMESPACE       |           NAME            | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
| default              | kubernetes                | No node port |     |
| default              | mysql                     |         3306 |     |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                  | No node port |     |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |     |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard      | No node port |     |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
```

If I try `minikube service mysql --url` it gives me:

❌  Exiting due to SVC_UNREACHABLE: service not available: no running pod for service mysql found

Not entirely sure what to do here;

1. Why does it not provide me the external ip 1.2.4.8
2. Why doesn't the node port get shown?
3. Why doesn't the --url work when the service seems to show up on the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because a service exists doesn’t mean the deployment succeeded. It says a pod isn’t running for the service. Your service Wants to find pods providing `app: mysql` while your deployment will deploy `app: database`. Since you probably don’t have any pods with label `app: mysql` then nothing provides the service.

Fix the labels to match.

Comment: Okay if there's a url that gets provided now, but I can't connect to it from local host. Would you happen to know why it picks some random high port and why can't I connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is usually determined by a selector that you define. Since you have defined the selector `app: mysql` it is scanning the pods that match this selector and as per kubernetes documentation  *"controller for the Service continuously scans for Pods that match its selector, and then makes any necessary updates to the set of EndpointSlices for the Service"*. You can make sure your service definition using this command `kubectl get svc mysql -o yaml` or the equivalent in the minikube.
2. Now change the pod name defined in the deployment yaml file in this below code from `database` to `mysql`, or vice-versa in the service from `mysql` to `database`. You can make sure the correct labels defined in the deployment yaml file using this command `kubectl get deployment database -o yaml`

```
 template:
   metadata:
    labels:
      app: database
```